# Helicicity operator of a particle

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, momentum, quantum-spin, helicity

How can one project the spin of a particle along the direction of momentum as they belong to different bases?
Or is it allowed because there are infinitely many bases connected through similarity  transformation and we can go to a "higher dimensional" basis where they both belong to a single bases?

Answer (score 0):

> How can one project the spin of a particle along the direction of momentum as they belong to different bases?

Spin states are an abstract concept, but the momentum eigenstates are not.  So they are independent of one another.

> Or is it allowed because there are infinitely many bases connected through similarity transformation and we can go to a "higher dimensional" basis where they both belong to a single bases?

I wrote this answer, which I think is correct, in the hope that some with more experience than I would tell both of us that if it is  correct or not, and that your question immediately above is founded on an incorrect assumption about the role and properties of similarity  transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Both the momentum and the angular momentum are vectors in space. To compute the helicity, one merely needs to know the direction of the momentum vector, i.e. the unit vector in the direction of the momentum vector. In other words, the fact the these are different quantities does not play a role. The helicity is the component of the angular momentum vector in the *direction* of the momentum.